# What is the typeURL for a String in a protobuf any Field

Tags: protocol-buffers

in Protobuf an any-Field consists of a data buffer and a typeURL describing the underlaying format.

Question: If I want to put a String into my any-field, what is the correct typeURL?

Comment: The correct typeURLis arbitrary "URL that acts as a globally unique identifier". That would be maybe a sender name maybe a predefined type name or something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the same question recently, however, after having read the doc I'm afraid we're looking in the wrong direction, as the [doc of Any](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/java/com/google/protobuf/Any) says

> `Any` contains an arbitrary serialized protocol buffer message along with a
>    URL that describes the type of the serialized message.

See? It's designed to hold a message. As `string` is not a message at all, so you should design a new message and make the string the only field of the message.

```
message ExampleString {
    string TheField = 1
}
```

Answer (score 3):

string url type should be `type.googleapis.com/google.protobuf.StringValue`

say your message is

```
message Person {
  google.protobuf.Any any_value = 1;
}
```

Then you can generate AnyValue with string value like this:

```
import (
  "github.com/golang/protobuf/ptypes/wrappers"
  "github.com/golang/protobuf/ptypes"
  "github.com/golang/protobuf/jsonpb"
)

A := &wrappers.StringValue{Value: "Hello!"}

any, err := ptypes.MarshalAny(A)
p := &pb.Person{
  AnyValue: any,
}

m := jsonpb.Marshaler{}
result, err := m.MarshalToString(p)
fmt.Println(result)
```

would print something like:

```
{anyValue":{"@type":"type.googleapis.com/google.protobuf.StringValue","value":"Hello!"}}
```

Other primitive wrappers are here: https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/master/src/google/protobuf/wrappers.proto

Note: make sure to import wrappers in your main

```
_ "github.com/golang/protobuf/ptypes/wrappers"
```